# JS animation skips spaces in text

Tags: javascript, animation

Im learning to make animations here and I don't know why my code skips the spaces in the text when converting string into separate letters. The source code is from Anime.js and it is working there just fine, but it does not work for me locally on my PC. Basically the text is all one word, no spaces. Here is the code:

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> -- Anime --</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="anime1.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1 class="ml2">LOOK AT ME NOW !!!!</h1>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.0.2/anime.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="anime1.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

and JS

```
textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(/\S/g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>");

anime.timeline({loop: true})
  .add({
    targets: '.ml2 .letter',
    scale: [4,1],
    opacity: [0,1],
    translateZ: 0,
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    duration: 950,
    delay: (el, i) => 70*i
  }).add({
    targets: '.ml2',
    opacity: 0,
    duration: 1000,
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    delay: 1000
  });
```

Any ideas what am I missing?

Comment: Well, your regex is "everything except spaces" so it's no surprise it's skipping spaces. Try `.` instead of `\S`.

Comment: tried it, now there are spaces but no animation

Comment: It shouldn't have broken the animation, I don't think... I don't know about the library you're using. I have my own custom animation library for this kind of thing (which fully supports arbitrarily-nested HTML as well as `<!-- commands -->` to affect animation behaviour) so I'm not sure what more to suggest on this one.